# Booting from Windows XP SP3 DVD causes BSOD

Tags: windows-xp, dvd, bsod

I want to repair/install the Windows XP installation on my triple-boot laptop (Win9 and Ubuntu) but when I try to boot from the Windows XP SP3 DVD I get a BSOD. The only things that have changed on the laptop since I first installed XP are more RAM and a new hard disk.

Comment: is that a DELL Computer?

Comment: [Are you going to tell us what the message **actually says**, or are you content with the rest of the world giving you random guesses based upon zero data?](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html)

Comment: Remove some ram, you can put it back after XP is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some ocassion I have a similar issue, the reason for the BSOD (sometimes the hard disk was not detected) with the installed of WinXP SP3 was that the hard drive was configured in BIOS as AHCI, Windows XP seems to have issues with this mode and works better with the IDE (Legacy) mode.

However, if this is the cause of your problem you cannot just change the option, this would cause the other operating systems (configured for AHCI) to stop working and have to be repaired/configured to work with IDE mode which is not always easy to do.